# POST 400 (Bad Request) in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap

I tried to post order list from my app to django backend. But it shows some error 400 bad request post with error **{message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'Error', description: undefined, number: undefined, fileName: undefined, …}**.

I think the problem is with my Items. If I Change my items in data state into " " and set my axios items to "1" it work perfectly just find. How to fix this ?

[image: Django redoc]

Here's my code example:

```
    const url= "http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/order/";
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        fullname: " ",
        phone_number: " ",
        email: " ",
        address: " ",
        post_code: " ",
        city: " ",
        region: " ",
        note: " ",
        items: [
            {
                product_id: "1",
                pcs: "1",
            }
        ]


    })

    function submit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post(url,{
            fullname: data.fullname,
            phone_number: data.phone_number,
            email: data.email,
            address: data.address,
            post_code: data.post_code,
            city: data.city,
            region: data.region,
            note: data.note,
            items: [
                {
                    product_id: data.items[0],
                    pcs: data.items[0],
                }
            ]
        })
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(err => 
            console.error(err.toJSON())
        )
    }
```

Comment: why aren't you simply doing `axios.post(url, data)` ?

Comment: can I simply do that ? but it show the same error

Comment: yes, you can. and yes it won't solve your issue - because your state does not seem to have some mandatory values for the backend. and the bug is in place where you update that state

Comment: can you provide more details on how that state is "connected" to some UI ?

Comment: for the fullname and the other is connected by form, and when on change the value of fullname and the other will change (it's already working just fine). Meanwhile for the Items it's suppose to get the react-use-cart items object and pass it to the databaase (this is where I struggle). that's why I tried only to pas fixed value ("1").